# Python: how to set given curve object to `EDIT` mode?

Tags: python, bezier-curves

When I go to `EDIT` mode using one of these two commands:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

I can see in the `Outliner` → `Scenes` that a curve object is selected.

But how to set another given curve object to `EDIT` mode ?

=== EDIT ===

When selecting a curve from the menu as active curve and then playing with these commands:

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['BezierCurve.001']
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['BezierCurve']
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

It seems I'm getting a little display bug misleading about the active object

[image]

Comment: you have to select the object first before calling `bpy.ops`. either by manual selection or select via python with `obj.select_set(True)`

Comment: Actually you have to set `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = your_object` since edit mode is based on the active object, not necessarily the selected object.

Comment: ah good point, i forgot that line thanks!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie if I set another object as active, I will see both objects in EDIT mode.

Comment: only 1 object can be active, the rest is only selected. all selected objects will get into edit mode. question though is what is your goal, what is the problem u are trying to solve?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I'm new to Blender and just trying to undestand it through a little project, Blender seems easier for me to understand through the Python API.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I think I got it now. It seems there's a little display bug when selecting an object from the menu then playing with the Python API (I have updated my post to show it).